# D3.Js charts in excel

Tags: excel, d3.js, charts

I am new to d3.js charts in excel. I read about plugin that converts excel charts to D3 charts. What are the ways I can use d3 charts in excel.
I tried the plugin available in excel 2013. But did not find it user friendly to add dynamic data. Saw come VBA code. Still not getting a full idea.
please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow not a discussion forum, but instead is all about *specific* questions with *specific* answers. You will get better results if you describe exactly what you are trying to do, and how you have tried to do it so far (include the *names* of tools, not just descriptions). Right now, it's hard to tell what tools you are using and what you are trying to do, so this question might get closed. The Help Center has tips on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- they will help you get better results!

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if it is a way to use D3.js library in Excel there is an easy way to do this.

I took an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) from the D3.js gallery so you can understand how it works:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a9944876f64c953db85be21

I used an onine editor with an embedded spreadsheet so you can have the excel data.

When the data is on the spreadsheet you can use it with Javascript by using a JSON file, `short` file underneath **settings**:

```
{
    "data": "=A1:C252"
}
```

once you have access to your data you can build your D3.js chart, and use your data by calling `$internal.data`, like so:

```
var dot = table2dot($internal.data);

var xxx = dot.map(function (d) { return { id: d[0] } })

f(xxx)
```

f(xxx) is the function that will create your chart with the values xxx.

You can then upload your chart in excel by pasting the URL in the [Funfun Excel add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like with my example:

[image: d3]

This is how you can use D3.js charts in excel. Hope this is what you were asking for :), if not please be more specific.

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**